# How do I get two non-related React components to work together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying all day to get this to work. I am building a recipe box and I have a modal that pops up when a user clicks Add Recipe or when a user clicks Edit on a pre-existing recipe. So AddBox is its own component that can handle both adds and edits (eventually I hope). Problem is for editing, the AddBox is kind of its own component that is a direct child of the index.jsx file but needs information from the Recipe component (i.e. the recipe that needs editing, to fill into the AddBox so the user can edit away). The Recipe component is a child of RecipeList which is a child of index.jsx.

Here is what I want to happen:

1. User clicks Edit on any given recipe they want to edit, that sends the recipe to edit back up to index.jsx to update state (recipeToEdit below)
2. Modal box pops up with the text area elements filled in with that recipes info, getting it from state passed down from index.jsx
3. user edits away, saves the recipe into localStorage and state

This is the edit button that triggers the callback function and the edit modal to pop up:

```
    <button type='edit' id='editButton' className='btn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addPopUp' 
     onClick={event => this.props.handleRecipe(event.target.parentNode.parentNode.id, event.target.id)}>Edit</button>
```

This is what is passed to my AddBox, a handler and the recipe to edit itself:

```
    <AddBox handleRecipe={this.handleRecipe.bind(this)} editRecipe={this.state.recipeToEdit} />
```

here is the important part of the handleRecipe callback for editing:

```
    else if (btnType === 'editButton') {  
    console.log('edit fired')          
        this.setState({
            recipeToEdit: recipeArr[ind]
        })
    }
```

So a user clicks Edit, this function gets called, recipeToEdit gets updated in state with the recipe object that was clicked and I pass recipeToEdit to Addbox (see above)

But within Addbox, I try to pass props.editRecipe.recipeName etc. to state because I thought it would update, but it does not...

```
            this.state = {
        recipeVal: props.editRecipe.recipeName,
        ingredientsVal: props.editRecipe.ingredients,
        instructionsVal: props.editRecipe.instructions
    };
}
```

I display these below in the addbox in various spots in the form. I am at a complete loss.

Comment: I just posted an answer, but I have a question as well: Why are you initializing state with values from props? If you have them in props, there's no need to put them in state. Also, are you sure you are correctly updating state whenever the component receives new props?

Comment: Hey, I think I did that while trying to debug this problem. Ya know when you are working on something and you go, 'maybe this is it!' because you are so into the problem and lost that you try anything...that is where I was. I went back and fixed it. Thanks for your suggestion, I am going to learn Redux soon, on the list...but for now I will try to work the component situation better.

Answer (score 1):

### Sharing state

What you are essentially doing here is sharing state between your components. There are two broadly accepted, good ways of doing this:

1. Passing values and setters from the top component that uses it
2. Using a state sharing framework like Flux, Redux, etc.

In both 1. and 2. it's important that you don't set selected recipe to the state of a component *until* it's passed from the Store or the top component. Always let the value take the round trip, so that the Store/Top component is guaranteed to hold the value used by the other components.

It seems in your case the common ancestor is quite far removed, and thus it might be easier to use the second approach. What you do then, is listen to a common state (some other, non-react component, typically called a Store) for selected recipe, and when appripriate, change selected recipe in the store.

If you don't want to go with the 2nd solution, you can either try to get the two components to have a closer common ancestor, or you can just pass the prop all the way down from index.jsx -- although the latter is probably not a good idea.